# Get record from array in single line

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array e.g

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 71
            [sku] => cp1038
            [name] => Dual tone stripped pillow
            [slug] => dual-tone-stripped-pillow-222
            [route_id] => 152
            [description] => 

Address Home, a brand new Luxe Lifestyle boutique, Everything from plus bed and table Linen to cushions, curtain and upholstery fabric in silk, cotton, satin, velvet, jacquard and polyester, embellished with foil printing, contemporary embroidery, crystals, quilting and other types of texturing, includin so much I JUST knew there was something really exciting coming up. And how right I was!

            [excerpt] => Dual tone stripped pillow 2 exec
            [price] => 1000.00
            [saleprice] => 0.00
            [free_shipping] => 0
            [shippable] => 1
            [taxable] => 1
            [fixed_quantity] => 0
            [weight] => 10
            [track_stock] => 1
            [quantity] => -93
            [related_products] => 
            [images] => {"0c2ef0ca18f628641cd55fdfbcbfb4ad":{"filename":"0c2ef0ca18f628641cd55fdfbcbfb4ad.jpg","alt":"","caption":"","primary":true},"ac632a9f43216dce4b643b6164bb5891":{"filename":"ac632a9f43216dce4b643b6164bb5891.jpg","alt":"","caption":""},"4623ecf1d9448868fb5ec868ba2292f8":{"filename":"4623ecf1d9448868fb5ec868ba2292f8.jpg","alt":"","caption":""},"1df39f0e7e6d95c7a6f429ed105cd045":{"filename":"1df39f0e7e6d95c7a6f429ed105cd045.jpg","alt":"","caption":""}}

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 73
            [sku] => cp1040
            [name] => Dual tone stripped pillow1
            [slug] => dual-tone-stripped-pillow-224
            [route_id] => 154
            [description] => 

Dual tone stripped pillow 2 desc

            [excerpt] => Dual tone stripped pillow 2 exec
            [price] => 1000.00
            [saleprice] => 0.00
            [free_shipping] => 0
            [shippable] => 1
            [taxable] => 1
            [fixed_quantity] => 0
            [weight] => 10
            [track_stock] => 1
            [quantity] => -8
            [related_products] => 
            [images] => {"bf2b5529299fa57b586cb393f374b69a":{"filename":"bf2b5529299fa57b586cb393f374b69a.jpg","alt":"","caption":""},"97c99c58f7d5e32b63a4f9f0b35b3167":{"filename":"97c99c58f7d5e32b63a4f9f0b35b3167.jpg","alt":"","caption":""},"e1b38b5aabc82e26c4920e0c36d28ceb":{"filename":"e1b38b5aabc82e26c4920e0c36d28ceb.jpg","alt":"","caption":"","primary":true},"fd19de4ef12d84dd5e0e6e9fca67f1c1":{"filename":"fd19de4ef12d84dd5e0e6e9fca67f1c1.jpg","alt":"","caption":""}}

        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 37
            [sku] => cp202
            [name] => Dual tone stripped pillow
            [slug] => dual-tone-stripped-pillow21
            [route_id] => 96
            [description] => Address Home, a brand new Luxe Lifestyle boutique, Everything from plus 
bed and table Linen to cushions, curtain and upholstery fabric in silk, 
cotton, satin, velvet, jacquard  and polyester, embellished with foil 
printing, contemporary  embroidery, crystals, quilting and other types 
of texturing, including tiny metallic pieces.


            [excerpt] => silk two tone pillow with diagonal stripes
            [price] => 1500.00
            [saleprice] => 0.00
            [free_shipping] => 0
            [shippable] => 1
            [taxable] => 1
            [fixed_quantity] => 0
            [weight] => 10
            [track_stock] => 1
            [quantity] => -43
            [related_products] => 
            [images] => {"0687014a0caff0874107272a5296e465":{"filename":"0687014a0caff0874107272a5296e465.jpg","alt":"","caption":""},"c0a6037628b6f19d6cb8c244cd79fb10":{"filename":"c0a6037628b6f19d6cb8c244cd79fb10.jpg","alt":"","caption":"","primary":true},"6e7dc08cedd9b54ca44bf7fd832f20c7":{"filename":"6e7dc08cedd9b54ca44bf7fd832f20c7.jpg","alt":"","caption":""},"4a74346e35a4b986e03ab69044cad44b":{"filename":"4a74346e35a4b986e03ab69044cad44b.jpg","alt":"","caption":""}}

        )
)
```

And I have id like 71, 73 etc. So I want to fetch the record from array whose id is e.g 73.

How can I get it.

I know this is not so tough but I am not able to get it in a single line.I can get the record running foreach loop of array and match my id but if I have thousands of records in an array then it would be wrong way thats why I am asking any direct way to get record.

Comment: you can make a string *single line*.

Comment: If you don't wanna use the foreach, try array_filter with a callback/closure for comparing the id. (That's technically still a loop though.)

Comment: @mario can you Please explain with any example. thanks

Comment: Yes, the manual contains many examples on `array_filter`.

Comment: @Bhuvnesh: you wish to get the data in one single line. Single line is probably a string, so access all fields and create a string from the data. Now, about search, there are various functions or any of the search algorithms, you can use them. search for it, your would get it easily.

Comment: The array what you posted in question is what you get output in browser... so can you get me array what you used in the code..

Answer (score 0):

First you have to take array in some variable like

```
$detail_array = array(); // your array
for($i=0;$i<count($detail_array);$i++)
{
  echo $detail_array[$i]->id; // you can get id
  if($detail_array[$i]->id == 73)
  {
     print_r($detail_array[$i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: this one I can do but it is the same to run a loop of array and match its id.I want in a single line like we do $arr[0];

Comment: Do you want this type "71,73" ??

Comment: I want complete record from array whose id is 73

Answer (score 0):

using array_search function you can get it

Comment: can you give me example if I want complete record of id 73

Comment: $record = $array_record[1]->id or print_r($array_record[1]) this will print

Answer (score 0):

first traverse this object like this....

```
$result = array();
foreach ($your_array as $key => $value) {
    $result[] = $value->id;
}
print_r($result);
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($result);$i++)
{
if($result[$i]==73)
{
//do something
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try [in_array](https://www.php.net/in_array) for search into array, like this :

```
<?php
$a = array("aa","bb","cc");
if(in_array("aa",$a))
{
  echo "get it;";
  //if successful do what ever you want
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't find a solution for this (except using a loop) in just single line. Because the function like "array_search()" or "in_array()" works only for single dimensional arrays and it looks like you have an 2D array.